# Xamarin Forms application freeze randomly?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, freeze, android-camera2

I have Xamarin Forms application which uses custom renderer to camera API 2 And on Android version of application he freezes and not working until restarting the application if there are any insights I can follow to avoid such action

Comment: Did you add the permission to your project? And it's helpful  if you can provide the full code .

Comment: yes all permissions needed are granted, the problem happens after application work for some time, not at the start of the application.

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: it's a complete project and code is private not allowed to share it.
 I need any insights about the same issue happened as it happens randomly and has no specific scenario to reproduce it

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer but it is not related to the current situation which I am in.
I think the app is going in deadlock or something like that it's not crash its freeze which means that the app is opened but UI IS frozen and can't do anything

Comment: Does it freeze when you open the camera ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202452/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-ahmed-khattab).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement taking photo and pick image from album in Xamarin.Forms . You can use the plugin **Xam.Plugin.Media** from nuget . And you don't need to use Custom Renderer and implement it in specific platforms any more .

#### Usage

in Forms

```
takePhotoButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

Form for details and features about the plugin you can check [Docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) .